# Spring test mock and object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, spring, testing, groovy

In short I have an entity that have references to other entity and this entity have reference... so when I want to test the first entity I have to create many more, related entities, but I don't want to ;).

```
public class Instruction {
    @ManyToOne
    private Model model;

    @ManyToOne
    private Color color;

    private boolean isActive;
}

public class Model {
    @ManyToOne
    private Type type;
}

public class Type {
    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
}
...
```

Other thing I don't really want to do is to change entities/cascades just for test case.
I was trying to mock "main" object by Podam (uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactory) but then I have `IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` error, because related entities are not saved.

Test code (.groovy):

```
import uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactory

class Test {
    private final PodamFactory podamFactory = PodamCustomFactory.getInstance()

    def "test instruction deactivation"(){
        given:
        def instruction = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(Instruction.class)
        instruction.isActive == true
        instructionRepo.saveAndFlush(instruction) // error on that line
        def color = new Color()
        color.status = "NEW"
        colorRepo.saveAndFlush(color)
        dto.status = "CANCELLED"

        when:
        someModel.changeFromOutside(entityOneChange)

        then:
        newInstruciton = instructionRepo.findById(instruction.id)
        !newInstruciton.isActive
    }
}
```

Simplified model:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public void changeFromOutside(Color color, changesDto dto) {
        if (!color.getStatus().equals(dto.getStatus())){
             oneEventPublisher.publishInstructionDeactivation(color);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround for this or some other way to mock entity w/o creating referenced objects?

Using Spring with groovy tests.

// edit: add some code

Comment: Can you add some code sample as well? It helps other people to understand your query in a better way.

Comment: If you don't want your `EntityOne` to contain a reference to `EntityTwo`, why do you populate it?

Comment: @Smutje if I understand your question correctly - I want have references in entities but I don't want to create all of it in test class, just mock them somehow.

Comment: I don't see any use in half-mocking objects, that only leads to tests that don't reflect the real code but only an artificial test case. If you don't want to mess with your repository to treat unsaved (mocked) entities I don't see any chance to fix this from outside the repo.

Comment: @Smutje So you want to tell me that creating and saving 10 objects with lot of lines of fake data sets rach, just to test one "if case" in method which use one property of last entity is better than create unimportant data by some automat?

Comment: As you haven't posted the code you are testing I have no clue about your use-case, so stop assuming things

Comment: @Smutje - as I said in main post, I "want to test first entity", but ok, we misunderstood each other, so sorry for my "far-go" assumings. I edit code for better understand, hope that show what I really want and mean.